# Xampp won't run mysql on Win7

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm trying to use mysql on xampp but i won't run on window 7 
It showing busy when i start it again.xampp control panel show the message.

[image]

[image] .[image: '']

> window msconfig shows that mysql is in "start pending"

Comment: Do you have skype installed in your system? Or check IIS is running or not?

Comment: I have skype but not in running state

Comment: And have not IIS installed on my window's yet

Comment: Check in services if it is running then stop it. By default it will on.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the my.ini file and change the port no 3306 to 3307 then restart the xampp server. I hope it will works fine

Answer (score -1):

it's mean port no on which you are try to start my-sql was used by sone other app.change the port no.,your mysql server will be start.